# Enabling 3D acceleration in Debian stable

Tags: debian, 3d

I installed Debian Wheezy on my daughter's desktop computer. It has Intel i5-4570 (Haswell) CPU and integrated Intel HD 4600 graphics chipset. No discrete graphics card.

I'm unable to enable 3D acceleration on the installed OS.

**How do I enable 3D acceleration on the machine that has Intel HD 4600 graphics chip?**

Below is some info:

```
user1@desktop:~$ glxinfo|grep direct
direct rendering: Yes

user1@desktop:~$ glxinfo|grep render
direct rendering: Yes
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 0x209)
GL_NV_conditional_render, GL_AMD_draw_buffers_blend,

user1@desktop:~$ xdriinfo
Screen 0: not direct rendering capable.
```

When I remove the HDD from the desktop computer and put it into my wife's laptop computer and boot into Debian, it appears that 3D acceleration is enabled. The laptop computer has Intel i7-3612QM (Ivy-bridge) CPU and integrated Intel HD 4000 graphics chipset.

Have a look at the results:

```
user2@laptop:~$ glxinfo|grep direct
direct rendering: Yes

user2@laptop:~$ glxinfo|grep render
direct rendering: Yes
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ivybridge Mobile 
    GL_NV_conditional_render, GL_ARB_ES2_compatibility, 

user2@laptop:~$ xdriinfo
Screen 0: i965
```

Comment: Haswell 3D acceleration upport is not available in wheezy. Have you considered getting newer kernels from wheezy-backports? Is upgrading to jessie (where it should just work out of the box) an option? Depending on what's good for you, we could suggest some steps.

Comment: @Ramón: Yes, I've installed the latest kernel from Wheezy-backports. But still there's no 3D acceleration. I've written to the maintainers of Mesa-Intel drivers for Jessie to create backports for Wheezy. So far I haven't heard from them. I prefer not to install Jessie as it's still in testing. If I can help it, I'll wait till Jessie becomes the next stable release, earliest May 2015.

Comment: For me, the acceleration started working after removing all *nvidia*-packages.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case the gallium 3d driver is loaded, in the second case the classic mesa3d. Try to copy the classic Mesa `/usr/lib/dri/i965_dri.so` in your desktop OS as Gallium driver is is not completed at the moment.